# Unrefined On The Inside

Tags: riddle

> My product, if bad, can oft be erased
>   In plural I'm located below the waist
>   In olden times I would quench a man's thirst
>   My travels are short and often reversed

Who/what am I?

Hint 1:

> I prefer paper to plastic when paying a bill

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This puzzle may refer to a:

> Drawer

My product, if bad, can oft be erased

> A sketch or drawing, if not good, may be rubbed out

In plural I'm located below the waist

> Drawers are an undergarment - may see Brent Hackers (thanks as usual!) for further discussion

In olden times I would quench a man's thirst

> A water drawer pulls water from a well

My travels are short and often reversed

> A drawer is a sliding box in a piece of furniture

Hint 1: I prefer paper to plastic when paying a bill

> A drawer writes a paper check

The title: Unrefined On The Inside

> Drawer includes the word raw

Comment: Well done!  Spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a

> Vein

My product, if bad, can oft be erased

> Varicose Veins can be "erased" with treatment.

In plural I'm located below the waist

> There are veins located below the waist.

In olden times I would quench a man's thirst

> A vein of water would be used in olden times to quench ones thirst.

My travels are short and often reversed

> Veins within one's body carry blood back to the heart.

Comment: Good try, and fits a few lines, but this is not the answer I am looking for.  There are veins above the waist as well. :)

Comment: @axavio This is true, but since it didn't say they were *exclusively* below the waist, I gave it a shot :)

Answer (score 1):

Could this have something to do with

> a keg / kegs?

My product, if bad, can oft be erased

> absolutely no clue at all...

In plural I'm located below the waist

> Kegs is a British (fairly northern I think) word for shorts or underpants

In olden times I would quench a man's thirst

> A keg is for drinking from

My travels are short and often reversed

> Well this IS true of the CONTENTS of most kegs...

Comment: Not what I am looking for. But I do appreciate the lesson on northern British slang! You are half right on that line, btw.

Comment: I believe it's "kecks" as the British slang for underwear.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham both: [kecks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kecks) and [kegs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kegs) apparently.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham 'Kegs' where I'm from... Never heard anyone use kecks actually...